# Equality of $2^x + 2^{4-x} \geq 8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Want to find the value(s) of $x$ for which equality holds in $$2^x + 2^{4-x} \geq 8$$

I've found it by solving $2^x + 2^{4-x} = 8$:

$$2^x + 2^{4-x} = 8 \Rightarrow 2^{2x} - 8 \cdot 2^x + 16 = 0 \Rightarrow (2^x - 4)^2 = 0$$

so clearly $x = 2$.

**However**, the notes I've been reading goes straight to simply say that equality occurs when $2^x = 2^{4-x}$, i.e. when $x = 4 - x$ and again $x=2$.

---

I'm probably missing something really simple here, but why does equality hold simply when $$2^x = 2^{4-x}?$$

Edit: to clarify, I want to know why is this is an 'obvious' condition for equality without writing the equals sign and solving the quadratic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could argue it by the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality:
$$\frac{2^x + 2^{4 - x}}{2} \ge \sqrt{2^x \cdot 2^{4 - x}} = \sqrt{2^4} = 4,$$
with equality if and only if $2^x = 2^{4 - x}$.

Comment: No sorry, I don't want a proof of the inequality. I know that is true, but I don't know why the equality occurs if and only if $2^x = 2^{4-x}$. Why is this is an 'obvious' condition for equality without writing the equals sign and solving the quadratic?

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove The kicker is the last line, which is part of the AGM inequality's statement: equality occurs when the terms are all equal.

Comment: OK, I see. It is obvious when you apply the theorem/inequality, but not 'intuitively' obvious I guess if you haven't seen it before?

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Look, "intuitively obvious" depends on the person looking at it. Whoever wrote these notes, when they solved this problem in their head, leapt from this inequality straight to $2^x = 2^{4 - x}$, i.e. the terms are equal. My best guess is that they used the AGM inequality to obtain the inequality, as well as the conditions for equality, so this was the intuitive next step for them. Otherwise, I just can't see why they chose to put $2^x = 2^{4 - x}$ as their next step (of course, I'm no mind reader!).

Answer (score 4):

If you divide by $4$, you get an equation of the type $y + \frac{1}{y} = 2$ for $y > 0$, which is satisfied if and only if $y = \frac{1}{y}$. This is a little bit far-fetched though.

Answer (score 0):

$(2^{x/2}-2^{(2-x/2)})^2 \ge 0;$

$2^x +2^{4-x} -2(2^{x/2}2^{(2-x/2)}) \ge 0;$

$2^x +2^{4-x} \ge 8;$

Equality for $2^{x/2}= 2^{(2-x/2)}$ (Why?);

$2^x=2^2$, or $x=2$.